# Is it safe to shrink the windows partition on a EEE?

Tags: windows, partitioning, eee-pc, norton-ghost

I've got an Asus EEE PC 1000HA that came with windows. As soon as I got it I installed UNR, leaving the windows, windows restore and fast boot partitions alone.

As its handy to have one Windows machine around, I restored the Windows installation today to factory settings. Much to my surprise, the restore didn't touch the MBR, leaving GRUB working just as it did before.

I saw during the restore that it uses Norton Ghost for its internal operations.

If I shrink the Windows XP partition, will I be able to restore to factory OS, without it killing the MBR or the other partition (that now sits where the original OS partition ended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done it with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). all [that is original windows xp and newly installed ubuntu ] worked fine.

Comment: But did `restore` worked afterwards, without killing both partitions (works as originally working)?

Comment: @voyager - restore worked; i used partimage to take another backup after i shrinked xp and installed ubuntu.